# Programa em C a funcionar mas não continua, dá erro no final

Tags: c#, c

Este é um programa que tenho feito para apresentação só que uma parte dele está a dar erros que não tenho conseguido resolver.
Aqui está o .h:

```
#ifndef PROJETOIAPG_PROJETO_H
#define PROJETOIAPG_PROJETO_H
#define TAM_S 30
typedef struct cliente {
char nome[15], sobrenome[15];
int id;
} CLIENTE;

int inicializacao();

int ler_clientes(CLIENTE cliente[]);
#endif
```

E aqui está o .c

```
#include stdlib.h
#include projeto.h
#include stdio.h

int inicializacao(){              
    CLIENTE cliente;
    ler_clientes(&cliente);
    menu_principal();
    return 0;
}

int ler_clientes(CLIENTE cliente[]) {
    int i=0,num_c=0;
    FILE fp;
    fp = fopen(Clientes.txt,r);

    if( fp == NULL ) {
        printf(nErro!n);
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(fp , %dn , &num_c);
        for(i=1;inum_c+1;i++)
        {
            fscanf(fp , %d  , &cliente[i].id);
            fscanf(fp , %s  , &cliente[i].nome);
            fscanf(fp , %sn , &cliente[i].sobrenome);

            printf(nid%d  , cliente[i].id);
            printf(nnome%s  , cliente[i].nome);
            printf(nsobrenome%s , cliente[i].sobrenome);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

O ficheiro Clientes.txt é assim:

```
5
1 Manuel Monteiro
2 Maria Fernandes
3 Ines Cornio
4 Fernanda Guimaraes
5 Fernanda Guimaraes
```

O problema é que não consegui ainda resolver o erro, já que o máximo que fiz até agora foi reduzir no .h o tamanho do char nome[30] para 15 e agora é possivel correr até ao fim mas ainda assim dá o erro:
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: Bem vinda ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/427939/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe, não sabia que existia o site em pt. Está traduzido.

Comment: O parâmetro referente ao formato de suas funções fscanf e printf é uma string e portanto devem estar entre aspas. Como você diz que o programa está funcionando então creio que houve um erro de transcrição pois, desta forma, não compilaria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só de olhar, este programa tem inúmeros erros, claramente você precisa estudar a linguagem do início, antes de tentar fazer programas. *Verbi gratia*:

1) Sua função `ler_clientes()` espera uma matriz, ou seja, uma coleção de estruturas `CLIENTE`, mas você passa o endereço de uma única estrutura (cliente). Ao tentar gravar dados do segundo elemento em diante, você já está sobrescrevendo outras coisas na memória, que acabam por fazer seu programa quebrar. E é melhor que quebre do que prossiga com a memória corrompida...

Provavelmente declarar `CLIENTE cliente[5];` resolve, embora fosse mais correto usar o nome "clientes".

2) `for(i=1; inum_c+1; i++)` geralmente as matrizes em C começam endereçando pelo elemento 0, então teria de começar com `i=0`. Mesmo que sua matriz estivesse correta com 5 elementos, o código vai sobrescrever o elemento `cliente[5]` que é na verdade o sexto elemento.

`inum_c+1` também não faz sentido como teste de final de *loop*. Deve ser algum problema na colagem do código, como o número de *loops* é dado pelo tamanho do arquivo, teria de alguma forma passar o comprimento da matriz de clientes como parâmetro adicional de `ler_clientes()` e testar se `i < tamanho_da_matriz`.

O tamanho dos membros de estrutura (nome e sobrenome) não é o que está causando problemas.